# Scoreoid & Java, HTTPS not working anymore

Tags: java

I am using the Scoreoid (www.scoreoid.net) to provide high scores for my game. I got it all working just fine, however after around 15 days since I registered my Scoreoid account, I started to get the following exceptions when reading or submitting my high scores:

```
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]:   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
...
...
...
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]: Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]:   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]:   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
...
...
...
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Tue Jun 17 12:41:23 EEST 2014
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]:   at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(Unknown Source)
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]:   at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(Unknown Source)
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]:   at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyTimestamp(Unknown Source)
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]:   at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(Unknown Source)
22.06.2014 17:11:06 [STDERR]:   ... 31 more
```

The only way I can resolve this is to change "https" to "http", but I don't want to do that.

Anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: I now realize that this might've fitted better into gamedev.stackexchange.com, is it possible to move it there?

Comment: It's likely the case that your certificate with them expired (there's a `NotAfter` clause in your exception.  Have you talked with Scoreoid to see if they could provide you with a newer certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't your fault. ScoreOid certificate has expired. I filed a ticket and didn't get an answer.

Comment: I can't help to get the feeling that Scoreoid is dying... even the Help & Support doesn't work anymore.. Can you or anyone else suggest an alternative online high-score management system for a desktop game? I'd really like to use Google Play Game Services, but unfortunately they are not available for desktop games, as far as I know.